# Spring Reactive: Combine requests and split them in the Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Hi there I am trying to solve a challenge with Flux.

My API calls another third party API that is very slow. I want to make sure that I call that API as few times as possible. For that I want to queue the query parameters. When that queue is full or a certain expiration time is reached I make a request to the slow API.

Example:

```
Request 1: GET localhost:8080/shipping?q=BR,CN,NL
Request 2: GET localhost:8080/shipping?q=LU,CA
```

Suppose my queue has size 5 and timeout 5 seconds. When the second requests arrives, my queue is full and I call the 3rd party API. With the results I want to respond each request with the right response.

```
Response 1: 
{
  "BR" : 21,
  "CN" : 33,
  "NL" : 5
}
Response 2: 
{
  "LU" : 1,
  "CA" : 2
}
```

How would I keep track of the request in an asynchronous way here? How to make sure that each request only gets what was requested essentially?

I would have a `WebClient` doing a request like:

```
GET slowapi.com/shipping?q=BR,CN,NL,LU,CA
```

And splitting the results into two different responses.

P.S.
I probably need to implement this using `Buffer` or `Window`, any experts on this area?

Comment: Have considered using a messaging queue?

Comment: Yes I did, but how do I split the response from the slow 3rd party API into two separate responses in my Controller? Do I need to store each HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse somewhere and return them independently once the slow API finished its processing?

Answer (score -1):

You want to do what people do with *long polling*.

Long polling is a method that server applications use to hold a client connection until information becomes available.

See [long polling using deferred result](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-long-polling#long-polling-using-deferredresult) for more details.

Having said that, this doesn't seem to be a very good (or user friendly) design for a synchronous end-point.  If the API is slow, you should consider making this an asynchronous request (with polling/websockets OR with callback/status end point in response).

Comment: I want to implement it using Buffer or Windows like explained here: https://www.vinsguru.com/reactor-buffer-vs-window/ would appreciate some help from an expert on the subject of reactive streams. That is the purpose of my exercise.